# ブランクスレート（BasicObject）のインスタンスでinstance_evalするのはセキュリティ対策になりうるか？

Tags: ruby, security

## きっかけ

> "x: 100, y: 200, z: 300" のような文字列を
>   {x: 100, y: 200, z: 300}のようなハッシュに変換する方法
>    　：
>
> #### パターン2 eval使う
>
> 超簡単(ruby怖っ)
>
> ```
> def to_hash(str)
>   eval("{#{str}}")
> end
> ```
>
> [Ruby 文字列をハッシュに変換 - Qiita](http://qiita.com/uplus_e10/items/65a50935250639bf8308)

を読んで、ふと
「`eval` 族を使うのは怖いけど、 `BasicObject#instance_eval` であれば `str`に何らかのメソッドを使われたとしても `NoMethodError` になるのではなかろうか。リテラルは使えるし、これって `eval` でのセキュリティ対策に使えるかも？」
と思いました。

Rubyist の共通見解として「`eval` 族と `method_missing` は最終兵器」というのがあるかと思いますが、 `BasicObject#instance_eval` を使うと少し気楽に `eval` できるかも、と考えました（速度などは考慮してません）。

## 具体的にみてみる

### 上記例を実行

```
$ pry
[1] pry(main)> str = "x: 100, y: 200, z: 300"
=> "x: 100, y: 200, z: 300"
[2] pry(main)> BasicObject.new.instance_eval("{#{str}}")
=> {:x=>100, :y=>200, :z=>300}
```

問題なくハッシュを生成できました。

### インジェクションしてみる１：メソッド

```
[3] pry(main)> str = "};puts 'hello!';{"
=> "};puts 'hello!';{"
[4] pry(main)> BasicObject.new.instance_eval("{#{str}}")
NoMethodError: undefined method `puts' for #<BasicObject:0x007fa980ca39c0>
from (pry):4:in `instance_eval'
```

無事に `NoMethodError` になりました。

### インジェクションしてみる２：コマンド出力

```
[5] pry(main)> str = "};`echo hello`;{"
=> "};`echo hello`;{"
[6] pry(main)> `echo hello`
=> "hello\n"
[7] pry(main)> BasicObject.new.instance_eval("{#{str}}")
NoMethodError: undefined method ``' for #<BasicObject:0x007fa9814fe0e8>
from (pry):7:in `instance_eval'
```

`str = "};%x[echo hello];{"` でも同じく `NoMethodError` でした。

### 定数設定

```
[8] pry(main)> ARY
NameError: uninitialized constant ARY
from (pry):8:in `__pry__'
[9] pry(main)> str = '};::ARY = %w[a b c];{'
=> "};::ARY = %w[a b c];{"
[10] pry(main)> BasicObject.new.instance_eval("{#{str}}")
=> {}
[11] pry(main)> ARY
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

設定されてしまいました。

### グローバル変数設定

```
[12] pry(main)> $ary
=> nil
[13] pry(main)> str = '};$ary = %w[a b c];{'
=> "};$ary = %w[a b c];{"
[14] pry(main)> BasicObject.new.instance_eval("{#{str}}")
=> {}
[15] pry(main)> $ary
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

グローバル変数も設定されてしまいました。

## 質問

`BasicObject#instance_eval` だと定数とグローバル変数が犯されうることがわかりましたが、そのほかに危険性はあるでしょうか。具体的に攻撃文字列を挙げていただければ幸いです。
また、定数とグローバル変数が犯されると、どのような危険性が考えられるでしょうか。

以上2点について、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

たとえば、puts は、

```
str = "};::Kernel.puts 'hello';{"
```

とやれば働きますし、同様に外部コマンドも次のようにして実行できちゃいます。

```
str = "};::Kernel.system 'ls';{"
```

また、定数を触れるということは、クラスも触れるということなので、クラスに対してなんでもできると思った方がいいと思います。

Comment: ブランクスレートの中にメソッドが入っていなくても、先祖から指定すれば他のクラス/モジュールのメソッドが使えてしまいますね。ということはセキュリティ対策にならないですね。納得しました。ありがとうございました。